# Prune command not working on Windows & M1/M2

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, monorepo, turborepo

I have a monorepo made following turborepo's [documentation](https://turborepo.org/docs/getting-started), on Linux machines it builds the entire monorepo and all the docker containers flawlessly but when it comes to either Windows (WSL2 on both 10 and 11) or Mac M1/M2 it doesn't.

The problem is that the "turbo prune" command doesn't correctly work, it should theoretically make a build of the selected package in container's root folder included with .json files, yarn.lock, etc... to then be able to copy them into the folders you want but it only fails.

I'm currently using yarn v1, with both turbo v1.1.2 (which works on Linux) and latest.

Something I tried to do was to manually fix the problems by adding all the required files in to each package at cost of turning each one of them into the root project and it still failed. So the steps I did are the following:

1. Normal build process (based on the one working on Linux):

```
=> ERROR [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker                                0.6s
------
 > [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker:
#9 0.620  ERROR  could not construct graph: Could not find turbo.json. Follow directions at https://turborepo.org/docs/getting-started to create one
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c turbo prune --scope=${SCOPE} --docker]: exit code: 1
```

2. After manually putting turbo.json from monorepo's root to sub-package:

```
=> ERROR [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker                                0.7s
------
 > [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker:
#9 0.459 2022/07/19 15:35:08 [WARNING] Did not find "packageManager" in your package.json. Please run "npx @turbo/codemod add-package-manager"
#9 0.600 2022/07/19 15:35:09 [WARNING] Did not find "packageManager" in your package.json. Please set the "packageManager" field to your package.json
#9 0.714 2022/07/19 15:35:09 [WARNING] Did not find "packageManager" in your package.json. Please run "npx @turbo/codemod add-package-manager"
#9 0.714 2022/07/19 15:35:09 [WARNING] Did not find "packageManager" in your package.json. Please run "npx @turbo/codemod add-package-manager"
#9 0.714  ERROR  could not construct graph: could not determine package manager. Please set the "packageManager" property in your root package.json (https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagemanager) or run `npx @turbo/codemod add-package-manager` in the root of your monorepo.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c turbo prune --scope=${SCOPE} --docker]: exit code: 1
```

3. After adding the "packageManager" option into the package.json:

```
=> ERROR [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker                                0.6s
------
 > [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker:
#9 0.584  ERROR  could not construct graph: yarn.lock: failed to hash lockfile: open yarn.lock: no such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c turbo prune --scope=${SCOPE} --docker]: exit code: 1
```

4. After adding the yarn.lock file from monorepo's root to sub-package:

```
 => ERROR [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker                                0.8s
------                                                                                                       
 > [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker:                                           
#9 0.676  ERROR  could not construct graph: could not detect workspaces: package.json: no workspaces found. Turborepo requires Yarn workspaces to be defined in the root package.json
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c turbo prune --scope=${SCOPE} --docker]: exit code: 1
```

5. After adding the workspaces from monorepo root's package.json:

```
=> ERROR [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker                                1.4s
------
 > [pruner 3/3] RUN turbo prune --scope=@mycoolproject/pack6 --docker:
#9 1.152 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
#9 1.152 [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7d4121]
#9 1.152 
#9 1.152 goroutine 1 [running]:
#9 1.152 turbo/internal/prune.(*PruneCommand).Run(0xc000059850, {0xc00001e0a0, 0x2, 0x2})
#9 1.152        turbo/internal/prune/prune.go:110 +0x3a1
#9 1.153 github.com/mitchellh/cli.(*CLI).Run(0xc00012b900)
#9 1.153        github.com/mitchellh/cli@v1.1.2/cli.go:262 +0x5f8
#9 1.153 main.main.func7({0x0, 0x8d6360}, {0xc00001e090, 0x819510, 0x3}, {0x0, 0xc00000e020}, {0x0, 0x0}, 0xc00012b900, ...)
#9 1.153        turbo/cmd/turbo/main.go:154 +0x385
#9 1.153 main.main()
#9 1.153        turbo/cmd/turbo/main.go:159 +0x9e9
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c turbo prune --scope=${SCOPE} --docker]: exit code: 2
```

If you manage to successfully build 'em all then most of the containers crash because they won't find the turbo module even if it gets globally installed during container's initial build phase, and they'll report the following message:

Furthermore, the build on a Linux machine works with both v1.1.2 which is the one we currently use to run it and the latest one.

For more details here is the [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/issues/1554) I opened.